# Can someone help me find installer Driver for Canon MG3200 for ubuntu/linux?

Tags: 13.04, printing, canon

Can someone help me find installer/Driver for Canon MG3200 for 13.04 ubuntu/linux?

Canon has only Windows driver available online.

thanks

Comment: No personal experience with Cannon printers.  However, From the Ubuntu Forums I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2115663).  Looks like it may help

Comment: It's not recomended, but here it goes, open terminal and type this, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon` , `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mg3200series`. Then open **System Setting** > **Printers** > **add** > select driver and forward. Now your printer is ready!

Comment: It support whole lot of Canon printers.

Comment: thx Shaharil/Warren.however, when i typed the sudo commands on the terminal it was  saying "Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~micheal-gcruz/+archive/canon) to get ppa information, please check your internet connection" looks like for some reason i am not able to connect the cannon server.but im sure my internet connection is good.I tried opening Warren Hill link and found it was russian..i tried to search the keywords and it worked - PRINTER -> http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100466601.html However the scanner didnt work i gues in nid some platform to run it thru

Comment: for the SCANNER -> http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100469501.html